# neteans hide packages from view

Tags: java, netbeans

I wonder if it is possible, to hide some packages (or directories) from the netbeans package view window.

Currently, I am working on a project, which has many projects, but I only know some of them.

I like the list view, so just collapsing it to a tree is not what I'm searching for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure,you've got opened the right view? Aren't you just in project/navigator view? (I dunno now exactly how are these called in netbeans). Try to go to window -> perspective -> reset perspective and then click on package explorer tab in left top box

Comment: ye, i'm in the project-view, and there is listed every sub-package.. i only want to hide, let's say all packages in the dir src/server/**/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide only some packages of some project, you've got opened. You can only show/hide whole projects. If you don't want to have so many projects opened in your current perspective, just click with you RMB to that project and click `Close`. Then press select it with LMB and press `Delete`. Just be sure `NOT` to check `Delete files also on local disc`, otherwise, you permanently lost your files!!!